# Regex to Replace Empty JSON Entries

Tags: java, regex

I've got a chunk of JSON that looks like this:

```
{"id": "2345", "in": "sadfasd647", "name": "Delta", "created": "2018-01-19", "updated": ""}
```

Unfortunately, the service I'm sending this too doesn't handle blank entries. I have limited control over the source, so I'm looking for some Java Regex that I can use with `ReplaceAll` to get rid of all empty entries.

The result should look like:

```
{"id": "2345", "in": "sadfasd647", "name": "Delta", "created": "2018-01-19"}
```

The closest I've got is this:

```
string.replaceAll(",?\"*\":\\", "");
```

But I'm getting this error:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 7

Comment: `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) //or Include.NON_EMPTY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex, also the first value could be blank and should still be replaced correctly:

```
(, "\w+": "")|("\w+": "",)
```

So your Java Code should look like this:

```
String json = "{\"id\": \"2345\", \"in\": \"sadfasd647\", \"name\": \"Delta\", \"created\": \"2018-01-19\", \"updated\": \"\"}";
String result = json.replaceAll("(, \"\\w+\": \"\")|(\"\\w+\": \"\",)", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Which prints the following result:

```
{"id": "2345", "in": "sadfasd647", "name": "Delta", "created": "2018-01-19"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (assuming the `id` is never blank):

```
String json = "{\"id\": \"2345\", \"in\": \"sadfasd647\", \"name\": \"Delta\", \"created\": \"2018-01-19\", \"updated\": \"\"}";
json = json.replaceAll(", \"\\w+?\": \"\"", "");
System.out.println(json);
```

**Regex**: `, "\w+?": ""`

**Output**: `{"id": "2345", "in": "sadfasd647", "name": "Delta", "created": "2018-01-19"}`

You are getting that exception in your regex because of `\\` at the end. This would be equal to a single `\` for the regex, so it expects a character to be escaped after it, while you have none.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Try replacing any empty string or whitespace preceded and followed by a comma (or by [ or ] if it occurs exactly at the beginning or end of the list) with null. It should work whether the actual JSON string has whitespace or not.

`String result = str.replaceAll("(?<=,|\\[)\\s*(?=,|\\])","null");`